# PHP Multidimensional array with explode() splits wrong

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, split, explode

I have a file called data.txt with the following inside: (three groups containing each three cars)

```
"audi,bmw,mercedes#volvo,fiat,seat#peugeot,..."
```

and so on, you get the idea.

Splitting the "groups" by the # with the php explode() works perfectly fine. However, when I'm trying to split the groups by the komma, it does not work the way I want it to:

For "$tablerow[0][1];" I just get the letter "u"(second letter) instead of "bmw" (second word as intended).

Where is my mistake (Code below)?

The $index_number just counts the number of those groups.

```
$datafile = fopen("data.txt","r"); <br>
$alldata = fread($datafile,filesize("data.txt")); <br>
$tablerow = explode("#",$alldata); <br>

for ($arrayposition = 0; $arrayposition <= $index_number; ++$arrayposition) { <br>
for ($tablerowindex = 0; $tablerowindex <= 3; ++$tablerowindex) { <br>
$tablecolumn = explode(",",$tablerow[$tablerowindex]); <br>
} <br>
} <br>
echo $tablerow[0][1];
```

Comment: You appear to be exploding on forward slash `/` instead of the comma `,`

Comment: Thanks, already edited it! Was just an issue of copying the code to stackoverflow, unfortenately not solving my problem though ;)

Comment: Did you mistakenly use `$tablerow` in `echo $tablerow[0][1];` instead of `$tablecolumn`?

Comment: $tablerow is the "outer" array (the first level), while tablecolumn is the "inner". If I want to adress an array inside an array, I need to use the outer array and specify the position then, as far as I thought. Nevertheless, trying $tablecolumn instead throws an error: "Warning: Uninitialized string offset 1"

Comment: Btw: if I just try `$tablerow[0];` I will get the whole "first group"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `$tablerow = explode("#",$alldata);` `$tablerow` is an array of comma-separated cars. e.g. `$tablerow[0] == 'audi,bmw,mercedes'`.

Later you loop over that array and split every element. But you don't touch the `$tablerow` anymore. `$tablerow` stays what it is. So `$tablerow[0][1]` references the second character of the first element, which is "u"

What you probably need is something like

```
$alldata='audi,bmw,mercedes#volvo,fiat,seat#peugeot';
$table = [];
foreach (explode("#", $alldata) as $carGroup) {
    $table[] = explode(",", $carGroup);
}

// $table[0][0] => audi
// $table[0][1] => bmw
```

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier.  Just `explode`, loop and `explode` creating a new array of rows with an array of columns:

```
$tablerow = explode("#", $alldata);

foreach($tablerow as $row) {
    $result[] = explode(',', $row);
}
```

Comment: Or as [one-liner](https://3v4l.org/cVZ0U):  `$result = array_map(fn($e) => explode(',', $e), explode('#', $alldata));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str_getcsv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) aswell after exploding your data by `#`.

[`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) will replace every element by the return value of the given function `str_getcsv`.

```
$alldata = 'audi,bmw,mercedes#volvo,fiat,seat#A,B,C';

$data = array_map('str_getcsv', explode('#', $alldata));
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/mXTLZ).